# Count author posts in certain category

Tags: wp-query, list-authors

I am using this code to only get authors who have posted in the 'Travel' category but the part `'category_name' => 'travel'` doesn't seem to work. The code currently gets all posts in all categories.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'exclude' => array( 10, 18 ),
    'role' => 'contributor',
    'category_name' => 'travel',
);

$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();

if (!empty($authors)) {
    foreach ($authors as $author) {
        if ( count_user_posts($author->ID) >= 1 ) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `category_name` is an arg for `WP_Query`, but not `WP_User_Query`..

Comment: hmm I see, but still not sure how to incorporate the count by category for users...

Comment: You can omit that arg and then loop through the users, then use `get_posts()` to check whether the users have posted in the specified category. Or you could also a use custom SQL..